# How to calculate weighted means for each column (or row) of a matrix using the columns (or rows) from another matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two identically sized matrices: `m` and `w` that look as follows:

```
set.seed(5)
m <- matrix(rexp(90), nrow = 3 , ncol = 3)

set.seed(10)
w <- matrix(rexp(90), nrow = 3 , ncol = 3)
```

I would like to calculate the weighted means of `m` using `w` as weights. To be more precise, I would like to do this for each rows (or columns) of `m` using the same rows (or columns) of `w` as weights. The results would be ideally stored in a vector. For example:

```
w_mean_col <- c(weighted.mean(m[,1] , w[,1]) ,
            weighted.mean(m[,2] , w[,2]) ,
            weighted.mean(m[,3] , w[,3]) )
```

for the columns, and:

```
w_mean_row <- c(weighted.mean(m[1,] , w[1,]) ,
                weighted.mean(m[2,] , w[2,]) ,
                weighted.mean(m[3,] , w[3,]) )
```

The code is very impractical when working with very large matrices. Would there be better code to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply do

```
colSums(m*w)/colSums(w)  ## columns
# [1] 0.2519816 0.4546775 0.7812545
rowSums(m*w)/rowSums(w)  ## rows
# [1] 0.2147437 0.5273465 1.0559481
```

which should be fastest.

Or, if you stick to `weighted.mean()`, you may use `mapply`.

```
mapply(weighted.mean, as.data.frame(m), as.data.frame(w), USE.NAMES=F)  ## columns
# [1] 0.2519816 0.4546775 0.7812545
mapply(weighted.mean, as.data.frame(t(m)), as.data.frame(t(w)), USE.NAMES=F)  ## rows
# [1] 0.2147437 0.5273465 1.0559481
```

Comment: Thank you, that first answer is very simple and effective

Answer (score -1):

We could use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(m) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), 
       ~ weighted.mean(., as.data.frame(w)[[cur_column()]])))
```

---

or we can use `Map` after splitting the matrix by column, and then apply the `weighted.mean` to get the corresponding means

```
unlist(Map(weighted.mean, asplit(m, 2), asplit(w, 2)))
```

If it is by row, then split by row

```
unlist(Map(weighted.mean, asplit(m, 1), asplit(w, 1)))
```

---

Or can use a `for` loop

```
w_mean_col <- numeric(ncol(m))
for(i in seq_along(w_mean_col)) w_mean_col[i] <- weighted.mean(m[,i], w[,i])
```